# Can't see some files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I have application which saves some files. When I use the open inside the program it shows the files in open file dialog.

However, I can't see these files from Windows Explorer. There is a small lock icon on these files.

Anyone know how I can open these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a permissions issue, if it's editing files in Program Files or other protected directories.  There should be a button, then, in explorer when you navigate to the folder, called "Compatibility Files."  That should take you to the saved versions.